# How to efficiently multiply and reduce mod n in an AVX register?

Tags: c, simd, intrinsics, avx

I have a __m256i containing 8 32-bit signed integers. I want to multiply them with another __m256i vector of 32-bit integers, but the result will not fit in 32 bit. But immediately after the multiplication, the result is reduced modulo a 32-bit integer. Is there some efficient way to do this operation on 8 32-bit integers in parallel or would I be better off switching completely to 64-bit integers?

And what is the most efficient way to do the same operation on a vector of 4 64-bit integers?

Comment: Even 32-bit modulo is hard (slow) unless you have a special case like a power of 2, in which case you can just use truncating 32-bit multiply (`_mm256_mullo_epi32`) and then truncate farther with `_mm256_and_si256`.  Even if you did use `vpmuludq` widening multiply (`_mm256_mul_epu32`) on odd/even elements, how were you planning to do modulo in general?  x86 doesn't have SIMD integer division, and there's no high-half multiply (until AVX-512 IFMA52) that would let you use a multiplicative inverse efficiently if you'd pre-calculated one.

Comment: If your integers are actually smaller than `2^24` (or `2^53`) you may have a possibility with FMA instructions. I assume the modulo-reducer is known at compile time?

Comment: I want to use SIMD in context of Montgomery Reduction, so the modulo is only needed for transforming the numbers to Montgomery Space. The modulus isn't known at compile-time, but it would be possible to precalculate something like a modular inverse or so. If the modulo is slow, it isn't terrible, since it's only done once, but it would be nice if it was faster than the plain scalar version. Another problem was how to multiply two 32 bit integers and then only keep the higher 32 bits of the result. Is there a special instruction for that operation?

Comment: No, like I said, there's not x86 SIMD multiply that only keeps the high half, except for AVX-512 IFMA52 which uses 64-bit elements.  There's only 32x32 => 64-bit widening multiply, so you have to do odd/even and then shuffle/blend back together.  https://godbolt.org/z/znenM9jPv shows how GCC and clang vectorize a modulo over an array.

Comment: If you precalculate R² mod N, you can transform a number into Montgomery space with the Montgomery modular multiplication itself